# C program not entering for loop

Tags: c, gcc

I am currently writing a compiler for a piece of University coursework. It takes X language and transpiles it into C. One of the outputs in C is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int integer,i;
    scanf("%d",&integer);
    if(integer <= 5 || integer >= 12)
    {
        printf("%d",integer);
    }
    printf("%d",(36 - 1));
    printf("\n");
    for(integer = -1;integer <= -5;integer += -1)
    {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
    i = -1;
    for(integer = i * i * i;integer <= i * i * (i + i + i + i + i);integer += i * i * i * i * i)
    {
        printf("%d",integer);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When running this code after compiling with gcc v5.4.0 and inputting 12345 for the first scanf, the program doesn't enter either of the for loops when it seems that it should.

I have a feeling it's to do with the pointer passed to scanf, but I'm not really sure since I'm new to C.

Comment: Fun fact: `-1` is greater than `-5`.

Comment: look carefully at `integer = -1;integer <= -5;integer += -1`

Comment: It is recommended to get used to using a debugger. Can save you a lot of time.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for your condescending answer

Comment: Please don't write any more code until you know how to debug, either with printf() or a 'real' debugger.  Also, don't use complex, difficult to understand/debug expressions in statements.  If you must 'i * i * (i + i + i + i + i)', (why?), then load the value into a temp var so that you can more easily step though with the debugger that you should learn how to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't enter the loops because the loop conditions are never met.

In the case of the first loop:

```
for(integer = -1;integer <= -5;integer += -1)
```

`integer` starts out as -1.  You then check `integer <= -5`.  -1 is not less than -5, so the condition is false and the loop is not entered.

For the second loop:

```
i = -1;
for(integer = i * i * i;integer <= i * i * (i + i + i + i + i);integer += i * i * i * i * i)
```

`integer` starts out as `i * i * i` == `-1 * -1 * -1` == `-1`.  You then compare this against `i * i * (i + i + i + i + i)` == `-1 * -1 * ( -1 + -1 + -1 + -1 + -1)` == `1 * ( -5 )` == `-5`.  So your comparison becomes `-1 < -5`, which is false, so the loop is not entered.

Comment: Thank you for giving a helpful and not-opinionated answer to the question